# Spring Data Redis: How do I know that MessageListener is ready?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-redis

According to the documentation for `RedisMessageListnerContainer` -

[public void addMessageListener(MessageListener listener,
                      Topic topic)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/listener/RedisMessageListenerContainer.html#addMessageListener(org.springframework.data.redis.connection.MessageListener,%20org.springframework.data.redis.listener.Topic)):

> Adds a message listener to the (potentially running) container. If the container is running, the listener starts receiving (matching) messages ***as soon as possible***.

The quote above seems to indicate that there is no real way of knowing when the listener is ready - or whether the subscription at all succeeds.

So, given that I publish and subscribe to a channel - how long should I *wait* until I can start publishing? In my tests, simply executing

```
container.addMessageListener(listener, topic);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   template.publish(topic, content);
}
```

means that I don't receive the first 3-5 messages that I myself have published.

How do I get around this without resorting to `Thread.sleep()`?
Is it possible to get notified about connection failure/success etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had that messages was lost when subscribing to a topic and then immediately publishing to it disappeared when I set up the MessageListener bean to listen to a dummy topic during bean initialization:

```
@Bean
ChannelTopic channelTopic() {
    return new ChannelTopic(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
}

@Bean
RedisMessageListenerContainer redisContainer(JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory) {
    final RedisMessageListenerContainer redisContainer = new MessageListenerContainerAdapter();
    redisContainer.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory);
    redisContainer.addMessageListener(messageListenerAdapter(messageReceiveQueue()), channelTopic());
    return redisContainer;
}
```

I can now subscribe to a new topic and publish to it immediately.